# Concat two dataframe from two different source. Unable to handle situation if dataframe missing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe, concatenation

I would like to concat two dataframes from two sources, both of them are having identical in structure but only difference in rows entry. And the problem I am facing is to handle on cases like sometime #input might be single, sometime none and sometime both.

My function is like this:

```
def CombiTwoDf(df1,df2):
if isinstance(df1, pd.DataFrame) and isinstance(df2, pd.DataFrame):
    frames = [df1, df2]
    result = pd.concat(frames)
    result.drop_duplicates(subset =None, keep = 'first', inplace = True)
    return result
if isinstance(df1, pd.DataFrame) and df2 is None:
    return df1
if df2 is None and isinstance(df2, pd.DataFrame):
    return df2
if df1 is None and df2 is None:
    return None
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Hi syangjali, can you upvote/accept my answer if you like it? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to create a list of your 2 dataframes while filtering out non-dataframe objects. Then if you have 2 frames, you can concat + post-process them. If you have 1 frame in your list, just return that frame, and if you have 0: return `None`

```py
def CombiTwoDf(df1,df2):
    frames = [df for df in (df1, df2) if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)]
    if len(frames) == 2:
        out = pd.concat(frames).drop_duplicates(keep="first")
    elif len(frames) == 1:
        out = frames[0]
    else:
        out = None
    
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

When the only inputs are dataframes or None (and not strings or scalars or whatever), this works:

```
def combine_two_dataframes(df1,df2):
    if isinstance(df1, pd.DataFrame) or isinstance(df2, pd.DataFrame):
        return pd.concat([df1, df2])
    else:
        return None
```

You could also use a try / except:

```
def combine_two_dataframes(df1,df2):
    try:
        return pd.concat([df1, df2])
    except:
        return None
```

Comment: Thank you Sander !! I will check and feedback you.